# Robocup Soccer simulation 2D learning resources

Tags: 2d, simulation, robocup

Does anyone know any good resources to start?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should first understand various important things like *format of sensor information*(server to client), various *commands send from client to server*, *UDP/IP communication* with robocup simulation server. For this you should go through [soccer server manual](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CEIQFjAF&url=http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/u/lammers/EDU/ws04/SimulationsAgenten/SoccerServer/SoccerServerManual.pdf&rct=j&q=robosup%20simulation%20manual%20feb%202003&ei=pjTBTb2aKs3QrQej3ITpAw&usg=AFQjCNEtZIVmp_JscGnHlsRLlg8FEr3Z9w&cad=rja).

Once you go through the manual, you can look at these libraries available.

[RoboCup simulation library archive](http://www.ida.liu.se/~frehe/RoboCup/Libs/)

Finally, you can download the source codes available [online](http://medialab.di.unipi.it/Project/Robocup/pub/). I would recommend you to go through **CMU's 98 & 99 source codes** and their **research papers** which are available online(just google).

If you want to learn more about **multi-agent systems** then you can go through **peter stone's** course ppts and assignments available [here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~pstone/Courses/378fall02/index.html).
For advance learning, plase have a look at **UvA Trilearn** team's publications and source codes available at this [link](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~jellekok/robocup/2001/index_en.html).

I hope these resources will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Best way to start is to rcssserver and rcssmonitor...
To do so you can do the following in ubuntu :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnurubuntu/rubuntu && sudo apt-get update
```

then install these packages using `sudo apt-get install`:
 1.rcssserver  2.rcssmonitor 3.rcsslogplayer
or download and configure these packages yourself in another OS 
[rcssserver on source forge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sserver/files/rcssserver/%22rcssserver%20on%20sourceforge%22)
the server and monitor will start up using `rcsoccersim` command in terminal.

Now you need two teams to start up a game and learn and develop, I recommend using Agent2d base team available on [RCtools](http://rctools.sourceforge.jp/pukiwiki/) because the UVA base team hasn't been updated since 2005 along the server and test your team against the Helios team available on the same web site make sure to download `librcsc` (4.1.0) that is a dependency for agent2d team.

It's useful to check out the [RoboCup Project](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/sserver/index.php?title=Main_Page) wiki and registering in it's [mailing list](http://lists.cc.gatech.edu/mailman/listinfo/robocup-sim).

Another way for learning new ideas is reading other team's TDPs (team description paper) Just search [pdf] TDP in google.
Teams like : Helios, Wrighteagle, FCPortguel and more.